# How can execute limit first and then execute order by use mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, sql-limit

The flowing sql first execute order by reg_time and then execute limit but I want to first execute limit and after order by.who can tell me what to do.

```
select * from user where province = 'hai' order by reg_time limit 0,20;
```

Comment: Have you considered a sub-query?

Comment: i'm considering

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do it this way round? Normally it would order them by the time and fetch the first 20 of them, the way you want it will pick some random selection and return them in time order.

Comment: I think it will not pick some random selection instead of it will return top 20 that match conditions and then order record.

Comment: This is the problem - what do you mean by the 'top 20', this method will just pick 20 from those that match.

Comment: There's no "default" ordering to tables. `limit` is *ill-defined* in the absence of (a suitable constraining) `ORDER BY` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange requirement, if you really really want that, you can try subquery:

```
select *
from (select * from user where province = 'hai' limit 0,20) t
order by reg_time
```

Comment: But which 20 will you get?  It won't be the earliest 20.